# Getting MS Project server 2007 project GUID

Tags: dataset, guid, ms-project, project-server, psi

I'm trying to access the dataSet for a project that I just created and published through MS Project 2007 client, however, it turns out I need the project Guid to access it programmatically.

Here`s the code I want to run, from the msdn website:

```
public SaveProjectInfoToXml(Guid projectUid, string filePathName)
{
    WebSvcProject.ProjectDataSet dsProject = 
        proj.ReadProject(projectUid, WebSvcProject.DataStoreEnum.PublishedStore);
    dsProject.WriteXml(filePathName);
}
```

Question is, How do I get the projectUid for the project I`d like to access!?
Why did microsoft decide to leave out such critical details?
Also, I can`t run ReadProjectList() and loop through all the projects, because my permissions aren`t high enough.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I solved my own problem

The method ReadProjectList() Requires elevated permissions to use. However, to simply get a list of all the projects available in the server,  The method ReadProjectStatus() from the project web service should be used, as so:

```
ReadProjectStatus(Guid.Empty,WebSvcProject.DataStoreEnum.PublishedStore,String.Empty,0);
```

It will return a list of the datasets of all the projects available on server.